# Can't get @Component to be inherited in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

In my project there's a common base class that all client classes extend. This has an @Autowired field that needs to be injected by Hibernate. These are all grouped together in another class that has an @Autowired collection of the base class.

In order to reduce boilerplate for client code I'm trying to get @Component inherited. With @Component not doing this by default (apparently [it used to though](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?45559-Component-Inherited-problems-with-test-stub-subclasses-and-autowiring-by-type)), I created this workaround annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Component
@Inherited
public @interface InheritedComponent {
}
```

... and annotated the base class with it. Its not pretty but I hoped it would work. Unfortunately it didn't, which really confuses me as @Inherited should make it work

Is there any other way to get @Component inherited? Or do I just have to say that any class that extends the base class needs this boilerplate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the `Component` annotation type itself needs to be marked with `@Inherited`.

Your `@InheritedComponent` annotation type is correctly inherited by any classes that extend a superclass which is marked with `@InheritedComponent` - but it does not inherit `@Component`. This is because you have `@Component` on the *annotation*, not the parent type.

An example:

```
public class InheritedAnnotationTest {

    @InheritedComponent
    public static class BaseComponent {
    }

    public static class SubClass extends BaseComponent {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubClass s = new SubClass();

        for (Annotation a : s.getClass().getAnnotations()) {
            System.out.printf("%s has annotation %s\n", s.getClass(), a);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> class brown.annotations.InheritedAnnotationTest$SubClass has annotation @brown.annotations.InheritedComponent()

In other words, when resolving what annotations a class has, the annotations of the annotations are not resolved - they do not apply to the class, only the annotation (if that makes sense).

Comment: Hmm, I thought i could do that because things like `@Repository` are annotated with `@Component`. Guess I just have to put a big warning saying "If you extend this class you *must* annotate it with `@Component`" boilerplate.

Comment: I believe those work because Spring classes that scan for the Component annotation have special logic to check the annotations of annotations - take a look at ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider and AnnotationTypeFilter. There may yet be a way to make your Component annotated annotation work

Answer (score 8):

I've dealt with this issue by creating my own annotation (heritable) and then customizing classpath scanning:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Component 
@Inherited
public @interface BusinessService {
}
```

Spring configuration look likes this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="io.bar">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation"
            expression="io.bar.core.annotations.BusinessService" />
    </context:component-scan>
```

from [Spring doc 5.10.3 Using filters to customize scanning](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters)