# How to retrieve the javax ConstraintValidator handled by Spring?

Tags: java, spring, javax-validation

As seen in this [Baeldung example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator), it is possible to write plain old `javax.validation` objects and Spring is able to manage them. For example, it is possible to perform field injection in a validator without annotating it as a component:

```
public class MyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyAnnotation, String> {

    @Autowired
    private MyBean bean;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
       return bean.getValidElements().contains(value);
    }

}
```

Yet, `MyValidator` is not a Spring bean: a `beanFactory.getBean(MyValidator.class)` (or an `applicationContext.getBean(MyValidator.class)`) will throw

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'my.package.MyValidator' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
```

This can be fixed adding a `@Component` annotation on `MyValidator`, but maybe it is cleaner to not annotate them as components: I have several validators that extends a common abstract class, so I'm planning to annotate that class [in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195970/inherit-component-in-spring), but I feel it would be more maintenable to just have a `beanFactory.getBean(MyValidator.class)` of sorts and keep each validator as plain as possible.

Is there a way to retrieve the validators without annotating them as components, as Spring already manage them somehow? A minimal example can be found [here](https://github.com/dcolazin/reprexes/tree/main/SO_77088418).

Comment: Why do you need to call this validator explicitly? The entire purpose of the bean validation framework is that you annotate your classes with constraint annotations (`MyAnnotation`), then let instances be validated. Validation automagically occurs in WebMVC methods if the request body argument is annotated with `@Valid` (other bean methods perhaps as well, not sure). And you can always autowire a `Validator` and call that directly.

Comment: @RobSpoor long story short: the validator is the object that has the task to know the list of valid elements, which is a configuration determined at runtime; so I'm using such list to customize the property enum in the autogenerated swagger.

Comment: For Spring to know what to do with the validator it needs to be a bean. Either through added it to xml, java config as abean or by annotating it with `@Component`.

Comment: @M.Deinum not completely correct, I added a reproducible example.

Comment: You are right. I keep forgetting that with newer Spring (or actual javax/jakarta validation) it is possible to inject a container through which validators pass (the same holds for JPA for instance). So yes this will work, but no they aren't beans they are still managed by the validation API and not Spring. If you want to access them through Spring you need to make them beans.

Comment: @M.Deinum this is exactly what I'm asking :) Spring knows how to handle the validators and the same validator instance is used for different requests; so such "bean-like" instance must be somewhere; possible that there is no api to retrieve them, without making the validator a fully-fledged bean?

Comment: To make them beans you have various options, xml, javaconfig or you could use component scanning. You could add an include filter that for each class implementing `ConstraintValidator` a bean needs to be created. That way you wouldn't need to change your vallidators.

Comment: They are not beans. They are created on the fly and injected as such. This is done through the `SpringWebConstraintValidatorFactory`. So there is no bean instance or whatsoever available.

Comment: @M.Deinum I would say that SpringWebConstraintValidatorFactory is exactly the class I was searching... and now that I read it, it might be a better idea to annotate them as components! If you have the time to post a summary answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Validation API has support to have dependencies injected into the `ConstraintValidator` based on the annotation metadata. This has nothing to do with Spring but is supported by the Validation API.

To support the injection there is the `[javax.jakarta].validation.ConstraintValidatorFactory` interface. Spring has 2 implementations for this, but commonly used is the `SpringWebConstraintValidatorFactory`.

What happens is that when validation is requested based on the annotations present the Validation API will call `ConstraintValidatorFactory.create` to get an instance of the needed validator(s).

Spring will construct an instance on the fly and if there are `@Autowired` or `@Inject` fields (or constructors), Spring will happily inject the dependencies.

The created validators are NOT Spring Managed beans. The lifecycle of those validators is totally in control of the Validation API and not Spring. As such they are also not retrievable from the `ApplicationContext`, unless you explictly make them beans.

To make them beans you can do 1 of several things.

1. Annotate them with `@Component`.
2. Create an `@Configuration` class with `@Bean` methods
3. Create an XML file to register them as beans
4. Add an `@ComponentScan(includeFilter = @Filter(type=ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = ConstraintValidator.class)`.

Either will (or can) result in your validators being Spring managed.